# Strategy for generating unique identifier for document in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

Say I have something like a support ticket system (simplified as example). It has many users and organizations. Each user can be a member of several organizations, but the typical case would be one org => many users, and most of them belong only to this organization. Each organization has a "tag" which is to be used to construct "ticket numbers" for this organization. Lets say we have an org called StackExchange that wants the tag SES.

So if I open the first ticket of today, I want it to be `SES140407-01`. The next is `SES140407-02` and so on. Doesn't have to be two digits after the dash.

How can I make sure this is generated in a way that makes sure it is 100% unique across the organization (no orgs will have the same tag)?

Note: This does not have to be the document ID in the database - that will probably just be a Guid or similar. This is just a ticket reference - kinda like a slug - that will appear in related emails etc. So it has to be unique, and I would prefer if we didn't "waste" the sequential case numbers hilo style.

Is there a practical way to ensure I get a unique ticket number even if two or more people report a new one at almost the same time?

**EDIT**: Each Organization is a document in `RavenDB`, and can easily hold a property like `LastIssuedTicketId`. My challenge is basically to find the best way to read this field, generate a new one, and store this back in a way that is "race condition safe".

**Another edit**: To be clear - I intend to generate the ticket ID in my own software. What I am looking for is a way to ask RavenDB "what was the last ticket number", and then when I generate the next one after that, "am I the only one using this?" - so that I give my ticket a unique case id, not necessarily related to what RavenDB considers the document id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use for that generic sequence generator written for RavenDB:

```
public class SequenceGenerator
{
  private static readonly object Lock = new object();
  private readonly IDocumentStore _docStore;

  public SequenceGenerator(IDocumentStore docStore)
  {
    _docStore = docStore;
  }

  public int GetNextSequenceNumber(string sequenceKey)
  {
    lock (Lock)
    {
      using (new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
      {
        while (true)
        {
          try
          {
            var document = GetDocument(sequenceKey);
            if (document == null)
            {
              PutDocument(new JsonDocument
              {
                Etag = Etag.Empty,
                // sending empty guid means - ensure the that the document does NOT exists
                Metadata = new RavenJObject(),
                DataAsJson = RavenJObject.FromObject(new { Current = 0 }),
                Key = sequenceKey
              });
              return 0;
            }

            var current = document.DataAsJson.Value<int>("Current");
            current++;

            document.DataAsJson["Current"] = current;
            PutDocument(document);

            {
              return current;
            }
          }
          catch (ConcurrencyException)
          {
            // expected, we need to retry
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void PutDocument(JsonDocument document)
  {
    _docStore.DatabaseCommands.Put(
      document.Key,
      document.Etag,
      document.DataAsJson,
      document.Metadata);
  }

  private JsonDocument GetDocument(string key)
  {
    return _docStore.DatabaseCommands.Get(key);
  }
}
```

It generates incremental unique sequence based on `sequenceKey`. Uniqueness is guaranteed by raven optimistic concurrency based on Etag. So each sequence has its own document which we update when generate new sequence number. Also, there is `lock` which reduced extra db calls if several threads are executing at the same moment at the same process (appdomain).

For your case you can use it this way:

```
var sequenceKey = string.Format("{0}{1:yyMMdd}", yourCompanyPrefix, DateTime.Now);
var nextSequenceNumber = new SequenceGenerator(yourDocStore).GetNextSequenceNumber(sequenceKey);
var nextSequenceKey = string.Format("{0}-{1:00}", sequenceKey, nextSequenceNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to make sense to me, so I will try it. :)

Comment: I have not tried to use this in advanced scenarios (server replication/sharding etc., multiple web servers vs. single RavenDB server), but after quite a bit of testing it has proven to work fine. I may need to find a way to clean up the documents that get stored in the DB, but I doubt that will ever be a big deal. Thanks again!